# Possible to reconstruct video from mbtree file?

Tags: ffmpeg, file-formats

I have a large mbtree file and found out it was used for video transcoding. Is there any way to reconstruct the video from the mbtree file or is it just (useless) metadata?

Answer (score 0):

It’s useless without the original media file.